# Is in this case P a probability function?

Tags: probability, statistics

**The problem is the following** If *S* is the set of the non-negative integers, and *F* is the class of all the S subsets. Is in this case P a probability function?:

For $A∈F , P\left(A\right)=\sum _{x∈A}\frac{e^{-λ}λ^x}{x!},λ>0$

I think that there's a theorem that could help me: *it's on cassella's statistical inference book*

**Theorem** Let $S\left\{s_1,..,s_n\right\}$ be a finite set. Let *F* be any sigma algebra of subsets of *S*. Let $p_1,..,p_n$ be a nonnegative number that sum to one. For any $A∈F, define P\left(A\right)$ by

$P\left(A\right)=\sum _{\left\{i:s_i∈A\right\}}p_i.$

(the sum over an empty set is defined to be 0) Then P is a probability function on F. This remains true if $S=\left\{s_1,s_2,...\right\}$ is a countable set.

But I'm not sure on how to apply it, or if is the right choice.

Comment: The expression is the sum over terms of a Poisson distribution.  Each $x$ gives the term for the probability of $x$ events, so $P(A)$ is the probability that the number of events is a member of $A$.  The total $\sum_{x=0}^\infty =1$.

Comment: Thanks! as a total beginner studying statistics that's very helpful information hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much to say here, but in order to be a probability function you need to satisfy the three probability axioms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms

$1: P(\Omega) = 1$: Here $\Omega$ are the natural numbers that you call $S$. Then $P(S) = \sum_{x \in S}e^{-\lambda}\lambda^x/x! = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n \geq 1}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!} = e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda} = 1$ as desired. Here we're using that $\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x$

$2: \sigma$ additivity: that is, if $\{E_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a countable collection of disjoint sets, then $P(\cup_{i \in I} E_i) = \sum_{i \in I}P(E_i)$. I'll leave it to you to see why this is true.

$3: P(E)\geq 0$ for every set $E$. This is also clear.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for kindly explaining me this, and for sharing the information.